# Ubuntu on SSD issue

Tags: system-installation, ssd

I just got my new laptop up and running with Windows 7.

The thing is my main OS is Ubuntu, and therefore I would like to install it on my SSD.

- The problem is whenever I boot up the Ubuntu installer it only detects my 1TB hard drive, and not my SSD.
- Any suggestions?

Comment: Check if the SSD is connected to the motherboard (small SATA-data cable).. I once forgot to check such a simple thing and wasted a good few hours on finding what the problem might be.. Also check if the SATA-power cable is connected - possibly swap it with the HDD

Comment: Is that the only solution? cus i dont really feel like taking apart a laptop

Comment: Well, you can insert a windows install disk or whatever and see if it detects it as well.. if it doesn't either the SSD is broken or the cable isn't connected. Sorry, didn't realize you were talking about a laptop..

Comment: Thats not the case, since Windows is installed on the SSD.

Comment: Hmm, if you boot to BIOS/UEFI, can you see the SSD is connected (boot order menu or whatever)? I don't really know why the installer isn't detecting it, I'm sorry I can't help you any further..

Comment: I will check that later about the UEFI/BIOS boot .. im not with the laptop atm, since im not at home... :) - Ty anyway, any suggestions is welcome =)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that i got it working, and it was basically me who was stupid and didnt have unallocated space ready on the SSD :) ... 

- I just found it weird, cus there was no unallocated space on the HDD either. Anyways! it works like a charm now :)

Comment: Glad to know you've got it working ^^ I'm sorry I couldn't help you